# Linking Curl to a CodeBlocks C project

Tags: c, curl, codeblocks

I am trying to link Curl to my CodeBlocks C project for at least 6 hours unsuccessfully. I googled and followed many instructions but nothing seems to work.
I have downloaded curl-7.54.1 as a .zip file, copied the curl.exe to C:/Windows/System32 and added it to Path. I can call curl from the command prompt successfully but I cannot figure out how to link the library to my project.

I tried copying the curl folder to my project folder, I tried linking the libraries from the Compiler Settings in CodeBlocks, I tried various combinations of Linker libraries, Other linker settings, etc... and NOTHING works.

I need some help to figure out how to successfully link this project, simple concise steps will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should download [the library](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) instead of the executable file. If you download a copy that have already been compiled you find the `.lib` file and go to the project settings in the IDE and add it to the linker tab.

Comment: Ok, so I downloaded the libcurl version and all I can see is a cygcurl-4.dll file. Can you tell me what I should do with this file?

Comment: As I remember Code::Blocks on Windows uses MinGW. That means you need to go to [the windows download section](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32) and find a suitable download containing development files. The 7-zip archive by Viktor Szakáts seems to include the MinGW static libraries as well as the header files.

Comment: Yes, that archive was my initial download, but I still don't know how to link those library files to CodeBlocks. Can you offer me some instructions?